# horizontal alignment cute spdt switch in circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I have hard time to understand how to shift the sw2 in `y` direction such that the `sw2.in` is perfectly aligned horizontally to `sw1.out 1` perfectly without any guessing. In the manual, no constants are mentioned. Please, can you help me find out how to align it programmatically in a dynamic manner.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border = 0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\customSwitch}[6]{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#6)}]
        \draw [thick] (0 - 0.5,0 - 0.6) rectangle (0 + 0.5,0 + 0.6);
        \draw (0,0) node[cute spdt #2, xscale=#3] (#1) {}
        (#1.in) node[right] {} 
        (#1.out 1) node[left] {} 
        (#1.out 2) node[left] {};
        \draw (0, 0.6) node[above] {#5};
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale = 0.6, transform shape]
    \def \xShift{2}    \ctikzset{bipoles/cuteswitch/thickness=0.3}
    \customSwitch{sw1}{up}{1}{1.75}{sw1}{0,0}
    \customSwitch{sw2}{up}{1}{1.75}{sw2}{2*\xShift,0.5}   
    \draw (sw1.out 1) to (sw2.in);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`circuitikz` objects are not set up on a grid; sizes and dimensions are very variable and can be tweaked by the "class" parameters.

So to build circuits, you basically *must* use the anchors of the objects and relative movements. If you look at the tutorials, all positioning is done like this.

So I suggest:

1. build the circuit, using the anchors and relative movements;
2. add the "enhancements" with a macro, using, again, the anchors.

I commented in the code; I hope it's clear the behavior...

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
% Add a box around a switch, and position a name above it
\newcommand{\BoxAndNameSwitch}[2]{% switch, name
    \draw [thick]([shift={(-.2,-.2)}]#1.south west)
        rectangle ([shift={(.2,.2)}]#1.north east);
    \node[above=0.2cm] at (#1.north) {#2};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    % draw the first switch
    \node[cute spdt up](sw1){};
    % draw the connection exiting from the first switch,
    % and position the second switch using the anchors
    \draw (sw1.out 1) -- ++(2,0)
        node[cute spdt up, anchor=in](sw2){};
    % build the boxes and put the name
    \BoxAndNameSwitch{sw1}{sw1}
    \BoxAndNameSwitch{sw2}{sw2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice the advantages of using anchors and build the circuit with relative coordinates. Suppose you need to add a coil and have a bit more space: you just need to do it, and the *rest* of the circuit will *not change*. Just one coordinate change.

```
[...]
\draw (sw1.out 1) to[cute inductor=$L$] ++(3,0)
        node[cute spdt up, anchor=in](sw2){};
[...]
```

[image]

...and if you feel that the switches are small with respect to the coil, you can add

```
\ctikzset{switches/scale=1.5}
```

somewhere in the preamble, and all will nicely fall in place.

[image]

Comment: I originally wanted to avoid this approach, but since it works and makes sense, I'll stick with this solution. Thank you for your efforts